# Single Quotes in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using PreparedStatement to execute queries for mysql database. I have written something like following:

```
String createQuery = "create table FEATURE(ID varchar(15) not null, ?, ?, ?)";
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(createQuery);

//replacing question marks in prepared statement
int i =1;
for(Map.Entry<String,Boolean> entry: featureBool.entrySet()){
    String col_final = "`"+entry.getKey()+"`"+" varchar(5)";
    preparedStatement.setString(i, col_final);
}
```

The problem I am facing is when this query is being executed, the single quotes are being appended to the beginning and ending to the string which is replacing **?** in createQuery. Can please someone help me out because I am stuck?

For e.g., if col_final = "Feature-1 varchar(5)" then in preparedStatement it is becoming 'Feature-1 varchar(5)'.

Comment: You cannot parameterized identifiers.

Comment: Means? Sorry but I did not get the comment. And if I cant do it, then what is the solution?

Comment: it means that you need to execute it as raw sql statement. since you are cautious with sql injection, you can create a validator for the inputs assuming that you are dynamically create a table.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are meant to be used for DML (Insert, delete, update) or DQL (Select).

Create table is DDL, Prepared statement are not meant for that. Please use statement instead and dynamically create DDL statement in java.